# No audio from machine, fresh ubuntu install

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I recently just switched from windows to Ubuntu 22.04. My computer does not produce audio.

My sound is not muted, I get output from headphones, and my microphone works.

In sound settings, it shows that audio is playing, but I can't hear anything. Perhaps the software does not recognize the proper output device, in which case I have no idea what to do.

Some information that may be helpful:

```
Host: JOE-LAPTOP Kernel: 5.19.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.9 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: Zenbook UM3402YA_UM3402YA v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: UM3402YA v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: UM3402YA.303 date: 03/26/2022
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-46-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

In sound settings, output device is 'Speaker - Family 17h ... HD Audio Controller.

I've tried basically all that is available online, which I think is nicely summed up here: https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Thanks in advance